# Thingsboard: How do i change main logo?

Tags: docker, device, thingsboard, graphical-logo, thingsboard-gateway

I currently have a Thingsboard installation with docker and all I would need to do is change the main logo of the web application to another logo. I've made several attempts by searching within the container but can't find any reference to the image in the application. Is this operation possible?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Shortly - Yes,

but check the user agreement first )

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61508188/5239616 answer after

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is only part of the Professional Edition of ThingsBoard. It is called White-Labeling:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/white-labeling/